# Spawning multiple processes with PHP to process data.

Tags: php, process, fork

I have a queue (Amazon SQS) of data that needs to be processed, and I would like to do it with multiple processes (in PHP).

I want the child workers to do something like this (pseduoish code):

```
while(true) {

    $array = $queue->fetchNItems(10); // get 10 items

    if(!count($array)) 
        killProcess();

    foreach($array as $item) {
         ... // process the item
         $queue->remove($item);
    }

    sleep(2);
}
```

I always need 1 child process to be running, but in times of need I want to (fork?) a child process so that it can help process the queue faster.

Can someone help me with a rough PHP skeleton of what I need, or point me in the right direction?

I think I need to take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php, but I'm not sure how I can use this to manage multiple processes.

Comment: This sort of thing isn't really what PHP was intended for or is good at. Forking processes is a lot more expensive than spawning threads, which is how this is typically done.

Comment: I could do this thing in Python with threads easily, though for specific reasons PHP is the only option available to me.

Comment: Well Python has its own issues with multithreaded code, most notably the GIL on CPython. Jython/IronPython don't have that issue but I guess need to be compiled.

Answer (score 3):

When you fork a process. you make a duplicate of that process. In other words the copy (fork) contains everything the original process had (including file handles)

So how do you know if you are the parent or the forked process?

The example from the linked page shows this pretty clearly

```
<?php

$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == -1) {
     die('could not fork');
} else if ($pid) {
     // we are the parent
     pcntl_wait($status); //Protect against Zombie children
} else {
     // we are the child
}

?>
```

To extend this to what you want

```
<?php

$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == -1) {
     die('could not fork');
} else if ($pid) {
     // we are the parent
     pcntl_wait($status); //Protect against Zombie children
} else {
     // we are the child
     while(true) {

         $array = $queue->fetchNItems(10); // get 10 items

         if(!count($array)) {
            exit();
         }

         foreach($array as $item) {
              ... // process the item
              $queue->remove($item);
         }

         sleep(2);
     }
}

?>
```

This will create on forked process ( a waste in this instance ) use a loop to create multiple processes. when the child has finished exit will kill the child process. and pcntl_wait() will return allowing the parent to continue. I am not sure about php but if the parent process dies or exits it will kill the child process even if the child is not finished. hence the pcntl_wait. a more elaborate system is required if you spawn multiple children.

perhaps rather than forking you should look at the range of exec functions?

A caveat.

forking process can be wrought with problems, database handles being closed when a child exits etc. You can also kill a server with to many processes if something goes wrong. spend a lot of time playing and testing and reading.

DC

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but looked like it could use a more complete answer.  This is how I generally spawn multiple processes in PHP.

A word of caution: [PHP was meant to die.](http://software-gunslinger.tumblr.com/post/47131406821/php-is-meant-to-die)  Meaning, the language was mean to execute for a few seconds then exit.  Though, garbage cleanup in PHP has come a long way, be careful.  Monitor your processes for unexpected memory consumption, or other oddities.  Watch everything like a hawk for a while before you set it and forget it, and even then, still check the processes once in a while or have them automatically notify if something becomes amiss.

As I was typing this up, seemed like a good idea to slap it on [github](https://github.com/twopoint71/php-mutli-process) too.

When ready to run the program, I recommend, doing a tail -f on the log to see the output.

```
<?php
/*
 * date: 27-sep-2015
 * auth: robert smith
 * info: run a php daemon process
 * lic : MIT License (see LICENSE.txt for details)
 */    
$pwd = realpath("");

$daemon = array(
  "log"      => $pwd."/service.log",
  "errorLog" => $pwd."/service.error.log",
  "pid_file" => $pwd."/",
  "pid"      => "",
  "stdout"   => NULL,
  "stderr"   => NULL,
  "callback" => array("myProcessA", "myProcessB")
  );

/*
 * main (spawn new process)
 */
foreach ($daemon["callback"] as $k => &$v)
  {
  $pid = pcntl_fork();

  if ($pid < 0)
    exit("fork failed: unable to fork\n");

  if ($pid == 0)
    spawnChores($daemon, $v);
  }

exit("fork succeeded, spawning process\n");
/*
 * end main
 */

/*
 * functions
 */
function spawnChores(&$daemon, &$callback)
  {
  // become own session
  $sid = posix_setsid();

  if ($sid < 0)
    exit("fork failed: unable to become a session leader\n");

  // set working directory as root (so files & dirs are not locked because of process)
  chdir("/");

  // close open parent file descriptors system STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR
  fclose(STDIN);
  fclose(STDOUT);
  fclose(STDERR);

  // setup custom file descriptors
  $daemon["stdout"] = fopen($daemon["log"], "ab");
  $daemon["stderr"] = fopen($daemon["errorLog"], "ab");

  // publish pid
  $daemon["pid"] = sprintf("%d", getmypid());
  file_put_contents($daemon["pid_file"].$callback.".pid", $daemon["pid"]."\n");

  // publish start message to log
  fprintf($daemon["stdout"], "%s daemon %s started with pid %s\n", date("Y-M-d H:i:s"), $callback, $daemon["pid"]);

  call_user_func($callback, $daemon);

  // publish finish message to log
  fprintf($daemon["stdout"], "%s daemon %s terminated with pid %s\n", date("Y-M-d H:i:s"), $callback, $daemon["pid"]);

  exit(0);
  }

function myProcessA(&$daemon)
  {
  $run_for_seconds = 30;
  for($i=0; $i<$run_for_seconds; $i++)
    {
    fprintf($daemon["stdout"], "Just being a process, %s, for %d more seconds\n", __FUNCTION__, $run_for_seconds - $i);
    sleep(1);
    }
  }

function myProcessB(&$daemon)
  {
  $run_for_seconds = 30;
  for($i=0; $i<$run_for_seconds; $i++)
    {
    fprintf($daemon["stdout"], "Just being a process, %s, for %d / %d seconds\n", __FUNCTION__, $i, $run_for_seconds);
    sleep(1);
    }
  }
?>
```